# Cakephp : How to save Arabic words into mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, encoding, arabic

I’m working on a project; I need to save some fields like having arabic character like first_name, last_name. 
The form is posting all other fields correctly except these fields.

I directly saved arabic words in database table but still it is showing ???? instead of original words.

I’m using Charset `utf8` and Collation `utf8_unicode_ci` with these fields.
Also on header I’ve  `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

I think it is some configuration issue of Cakephp because database seems okay. 
I’ve tried this so far, it is not working.

```
<h1 lang="ar"><?php echo $user['User']['first_name_ar']; ?></h1>
```

This is my database.php

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '************',
        'database' => 'projectimpossible',
        'prefix' => '',
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which collation used in database?

Comment: Latin1_swedish_ci but I can see arabic letters in the tables that were saved directly

Comment: Use utf8_unicode_ci and try

Comment: please add your database.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your database configurations defined in **database.php** under Config folder is incorrect. Here encoding should be utf8 as well.

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '************',
        'database' => 'projectimpossible',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

Thanks